# Check attributes of model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wrote a little code to test in wich atrributes of my model `Icd3Code` there are values that are longer than `255`. I do this because i first defined all of my fields in the model as `text` but not all attributes requiere so much space! So i would like to change some attributes to `string`:

My code:

```
arr = Icd3Code.new.attributes.keys

Icd3Code.all.each do |f|
    arr.each do |a|
        if f.a.length >= 255
            puts a 
        end
    end
end
```

`Icd3Code.new.attributes.keys`

gives me such an output and thats a problem:
 `["id", "abrechenbar", "alter_fehler", "alter_o"` Because there all `strings`!

Means that `f.a.length` returns a error:

```
method_missing': undefined method `a' for #<Icd3Code:0x7f395f0> (NoMethodError)
```

How can i fix this? Thanks

Comment: If you happen to be using PostgreSQL as your database note that there is *no* space or performance penalty incurred when using text instead of varchar (string) data types.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall thats a very good point! I didnt know that! You have to know im new to PostgreSQL! Before asking this question i tried to change my sqlite3 database to postgresql! And somehow i always got the error `type varching(255) to long` or something like that! So i changed my migration to texts! And then tried to find out wich attribute blocked my `db:seed`! But if you say there is no performance penalty my question is useless haha! Thanks! Maybe you can post a answer?

Comment: My comment doesn’t really answer your question as-is, and an actual answer is still useful for other databases where this isn’t true `:)`. (In PostgreSQL varchar is actually implemented on top of text which is why this is true.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is replace `f.a.length` with `a.length`.

I think you need to check values rather than keys of attributes.
Here is the updated code

```
Icd3Code.all.each do |f|
    f.attributes.values.each do |a|
        if a.length >= 255
            puts a 
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Sorry but i dont want to check if the field description is longer than `255`! I want to check if the values for example of `f.abrechenbar` are longer than `255`! Do you understand what i mean? Sorry for my bad englisch